# How deactivate the http-api

Tags: multisite, http-api, offline

give it an tipp or solution for deactivate the method request() in class WP_Http_Streams?
I use WordPress also on offline-servers and have wp_debug true for development and tests. But i have many warnings from functions to use the http-class; as example the functions to read the feeds in dashboard. Current i have deactivate all hooks for update themes, plugins, core and the crons; see my small plugin for this: https://github.com/bueltge/WP-Offline

Thanks for a reply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this in `wp-config.php`:

```
define( 'WP_HTTP_BLOCK_EXTERNAL', true );
```